# How to prevent users registering with specific usernames?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

I'm using the ASP.NET authentication methods and I want to prevent my users from registering with certain usernames. How do I prevent that from happening?

Is there a method built-in to blacklist the registration of certain usernames, or is it best to just write some checks in the Register method in the controller to prevent registration if they match any usernames in a list?

Comment: I will maintain a black listed usernames and check it against registration process

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but was wondering if there was a 'best practice' for this sort of thing.

Comment: Register action   in Account controller

Comment: Thanks Emil, I think I'll just add the check at the beginning of that Register method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

// ************ Check the username aganist the list ***********
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I would actually move that check to before `ModelState.IsValid`. Then, if an invalid username was used, you can do something like `ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "You cannot use that as a username")`. The user will then naturally be returned to the form to fix errors and will actually be told they need to use a different username.

Answer (score 0):

So it would appear that there's no built-in functionality in the ASP.NET authentications services to handle this, so the best solution will be to check against a pre-defined list of usernames and prevent the registration if there's a match.

With help from [Emil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003821/emil), I'll be doing the following in my `Register` method in the `Authentication Controller`.

EDIT: Following feedback from [Chris Pratt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654031/chris-pratt), we can add the error message to the modelstate.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (constants.BannedUsernames.Contains(model.Username)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Username", "That username has been taken, please try another username");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Continue with the existing code...
    }
}
```

Then we need to store the list of banned usernames, I already have a static class that holds static variables I use throughout my site:

```cs
public static class constants
{
    public static List<string> BannedUsernames = new List<string>()
    {
        "admin",
        "superadmin"
        // whatver usernames you want to block
    };
}
```

Comment: It's kind of bad form to answer your own question when it's already been answered, unless the existing answers are so far off the mark as to be irrelevant. That's not the case here. You should work with @Emil to improve his answer, if you feel it needs improvement or is not complete enough, and then accept that answer.

Comment: My apologies, I was building on what @Emil had provided and written the code that would do the check. I figured that may be useful to those who wouldn't know how to do that. I did not intend to detract from the very much appreciated help from Emil.